# Opendaylight netconf-testtool build failed

Tags: simulator, opendaylight, ietf-netconf

Hi I tried to clone the repository and build the source as mentioned in the opendaylight wiki page. But the build is failing.

Link: https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:Netconf:Testtool#Building_testtool

The following are the steps I followed:

1. Check out latest netconf repository from [git](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/netconf)
2. Dive into netconf/netconf/tools/netconf-testtool/ folder
3. Build testtool using mvn clean install command

The build fails with the following error trace:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.netconf:netconf-parent:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.mdsal:binding-parent:pom:0.13.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ org.opendaylight.netconf:netconf-parent:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT, /home/balakrishnan/netconf_simulator/netconf/netconf/netconf-parent/pom.xml, line 11, column 11
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.opendaylight.netconf:netconf-testtool:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/balakrishnan/netconf_simulator/netconf/netconf/tools/netconf-testtool/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.netconf:netconf-parent:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.mdsal:binding-parent:pom:0.13.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ org.opendaylight.netconf:netconf-parent:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT, /home/balakrishnan/netconf_simulator/netconf/netconf/netconf-parent/pom.xml, line 11, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build needs artifacts which your Maven setup doesn’t know about. You need to [edit your `settings.xml` file](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup#Edit_your_.7E.2F.m2.2Fsettings.xml); if you’re running in a Unix-style environment:

```
cp -n ~/.m2/settings.xml{,.orig}
wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml > ~/.m2/settings.xml
```

This will configure Maven to download OpenDaylight artifacts from [the OpenDaylight Nexus repositories](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/); you will then be able to build `netconf-testtool` directly.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much, Stephen Kitt!

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the entire netconf project (ie mvn install) from the top-down.

Comment: What do you mean by "build the entire project, top-down". I see pom.xml at different locations. One in initial `netconf` directory, followed by `netconf/netconf/` directory. But building both produce the same error. Can you please provide more details?